# Alternatives to global variables

Tags: ruby

I have a program that will grab several global settings from an API when first logged in. These values are then used extensively throughout the program. Currently I am storing them in global variables, but it does not seem very OOP.

What are the alternatives to global variables for storing extensively used settings?  Use constants? Class variables? Where would I initialize the values through the API call, since this would only need to happen once? I have seen some examples that instantiate a class to get to the variables but that does not make much sense to me.

I would like to set the values on login and after this call the variables everywhere else with a simple expression like Global.myvalue or GLOBAL_MYVALUE

Comment: I've edited the title and question to attempt to make this a simple list question rather than a request for any "best."  Opinion questions don't do well here, but list questions, provided they are not too broad, can be alright.  There aren't too many alternatives to global variables, so I think it's narrow enough to be on-topic now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Singleton Pattern might be handy for this:

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html

Comment: I've been checking it out and I think it would work. Where should I call the API to define it's attributes? in its initialize method? Or outside the class in the login method? Bear in mind the API call is asynchronous

Comment: The Singleton pattern gets kind of a bad rap some times, and in many cases deservedly so, but this is one of those occasions where it really may be the correct solution.

Comment: @Augusto - Not sure where is best. Async adds difficulty. I'm guessing you want your setup complete before you proceed.

Comment: @Augusto - You might want to explore the possible drawbacks before you go down this road. Singletons are controversial because they are prone to abuse and hard to test. Sorry if I opened a can of worms for you.

Comment: @Augusto - Probably beating a dead horse here but since we have wandered off into the land of Design Patterns I would like to recommend a book: POODR(Practical Object Oriented Design in Ruby) by Sandi Metz. It's been a while since I read it but I seem to recall an approach to dealing with API's either in the book or one of her talks online which are also great.

Comment: Thank you Seph! I'll look it up!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you a concise answer based on the information you provided, but I would avoid using global variables at all costs.

A good starting point would be to think of a class that could be a common ancestor to all the places where you use these variables and store them in that class. If your subclasses inherit from that class, these variables will automatically be available in their context.

Edit: like @seph posted, the singleton pattern seems to be a much better solution though

Comment: I would not recommend using a base class: Derivation expresses an "is-a" relationship, which does not exist here.  Also, Ruby does not permit multiple inheritance, so once you've derived from the settings class, you cannot derive from anything else.